# file-stream character ends with an object

Tags: syntax, lisp, common-lisp

I am new in Lisp, just did some tutorials before.
This time I try to create my own code.
I want to print all odd numbers from 1 to 20.

I tried to shift the brackets and syntax things like that.
This is my code:

```
(loop for x from 1 to 20

   (cond

   ((/= 0 (mod x 2))

   )

   do (print x)

)
```

And as a result I get:

```
*** - READ: input stream
      #<INPUT BUFFERED FILE-STREAM CHARACTER #P"main.lisp" @7> ends within an
      object. Last opening parenthesis probably in line 1.
```

Is there anybody who can help me?

Comment: you still haven't told us, what Lisp dialect you are trying to use...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anybody who can help me?

sure, you just need to balance your code or count the parentheses to see the error:

```
(loop for x from 1 to 20

   (cond

   ((/= 0 (mod x 2))

   )

   do (print x)

)
```

Above has 6 opening and 5 closing parentheses...

You need to check the syntax:

- unbalanced parenthesis
- illegal LOOP syntax

Here is a booklet with an overview of Common Lisp syntax: [Common Lisp Quick Reference](http://clqr.boundp.org/download.html)

Also: manually indenting Lisp code will not work: use the editor to do that.

```
CL-USER 6 > (loop for x from 1 to 20
                  do (when (/= 0 (mod x 2))
                       (print x)))

1 
3 
5 
7 
9 
11 
13 
15 
17 
19 
NIL
```

Comment: Thanks, I insert a closing parantheses ((/= 0 (mod x 2))). But now there is a syntax error. *** - LOOP: illegal syntax near (COND ((/= 0 (MOD X 2)))) in
      (LOOP FOR X FROM 1 TO 20 (COND ((/= 0 (MOD X 2)))) DO (PRINT X))